# Is there a way to know which achievement to go for next?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2

Is there an Achievement tool that tells me which achievements I should go for next in Team Fortress 2?

e.g. the easiest one or the one that that will give me my next milestone.

A similar service for Item Crafting advising is tf2crafting.info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently building a site that will show you the next easiest achievement you can go for to take you to your next nearest/easiest Milestone achievement.

I will update this post as I get further along.

**Update**: I've decided to create an achievement advisor at: [www.tf2next.info](http://www.tf2next.info)
It's workable, still need to put more work into it, but I've used it myself sometimes to look up what achievement to go for next while playing during lunch break when we are so lucky.

Comment: Your site looks good, but it does not work for me! When I enter my name, he seeks indefinitely without displaying anything other than the loading wheel. Keep up working! I would like to use it in the futur!

Comment: @SilverM-A, thanks, it really needs a lot of work still though (font smaller etc).  It should be working now, the issue was a 500 error on the data source (steamcommunity.com/id/user/stats/TF2/?xml=1) which steam has now resolved.  Hope it helps you too.

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas - your site has gone down

Answer (score 7):

An achievement adviser and a crafting adviser are two different beats.

Most TF2 achievements are unrelated to one another... which is some feat, considering the game has nearly 400 of them.

The Official TF2 Wiki has [achievement guides](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Achievements) broken up by class (and general).  These guides break down the achievements by difficulty.  It's recommended that you do the easier achievements first in order to get the associated weapon unlocks.

Comment: I've started to create a site to advise you on which one of the easiest achievements to go for - http://www.tf2next.info 
@Powerlord, you have almost all of them, wow you've played a lot :O

Comment: @DavidFreitas Yes, and sadly I'll likely never have the Replays achievements thanks to Valve not tracking Youtube's stats in real time.  I literally can't have it update my view counts for those because all my Replays were submitted from my old desktop, so my new one doesn't have those replays listed to update their stats.